# Updating Date in Access

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, sql-update

I want to simply update a date column within a table where a status exists.

Here’s what I have

```
UPDATE contracts
SET [Date Cancelled] = 21/06/2021
WHERE status IN (3, 5)
```

I have tried the following

```
‘#21/06/2021#’
#21/06/2021#
CDate(‘21-06-2021’)
CDate(‘2021-06-21’)
CDate(‘2021-06-21 00:00:00.0’)
```

Nothing has gone through, no errors, just not updating.

I can update the field manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers were correct, silly issue about the Trust Center ‘enable’ bar not showing, therefore didn’t realise this database location wasn’t set as Trusted, therefore nothing would allow an update.

Once location set as trusted, queries worked, thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [TableName] SET `ColumnName` = #08/02/2005# WHERE `status` IN (3, 5)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, this hasn’t worked, again, no error or problems, just simply not updating.

Comment: I tested it with my sample table and it worked. You should share your table and data.

Comment: The status column has no empty cells, range of 1 - 5, setup as integer. The Date cancelled column has empty fields, setup as Date/Time in design view.

Answer (score 1):

You need *octothorpes* for date expressions in Access SQL, and `status` may be a reserved word:

```sql
UPDATE contracts
SET [Date Cancelled] = #2021/06/21#
WHERE [status] IN (3, 5)
```